# How to config initial connection command for Django databases?

Tags: django, django-database

Can I do something like this in Django settings file:

```
DATABASE = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'test.sqlite3',
        'INITIAL_CMD': 'PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL',  # here
     }
}
```

so that whenever Django connects to `default` **SQLite3** DB, it issues `PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL` first before others.
And yes, for those familiar with PHP, I need something like `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` in [MySQL PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [connection_created](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#connection-created) signal.